# how to find MAC address in MAC OS X programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, mac-address

I am new to Mac OS X and X code and want to know how to find the MAC address of a machine programmatically in OS X.

Comment: Note that most current Macs will have multiple MAC addresses (one or more Ethernet plus Wi-Fi and possibly other interfaces too).

Answer (score -1):

**Bash Solution**

```bash
ifconfig  | grep -A 6 en0 | grep -o ether.* | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C and asks how to get the MAC address programmatically. Using a shell command does not answer the question being asked.

Answer (score -1):

for `macOS 13.2` :

> ```
> ifconfig en0 | mawk 'NF *= NF==2' FS='^[ \t]*ether ' OFS=
> ```

```
f8:4d:89:1a:73:d9
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C and asks how to get the MAC address programmatically. Using a shell command does not answer the question being asked.

Answer (score -1):

Try below solution.

```
ifconfig en1 | awk '/ether/{print $2}'
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C and asks how to get the MAC address programmatically. Using a shell command does not answer the question being asked.